# Javascript - How to parse propositional calculus

Tags: javascript, calculus

I want to make a propositional calculus parser with Javascript, which will elaborate the input and tell if the logical proposition is correct.
For example, I would type

```
(A && B) || (B && A) => not(A)
```

and then i would insert in another prompt the possible values of A and B.

I'm not asking someone to get the work done for me, it's just I don't know where to start. I'd like to have some hints: how could I correctly represent with Javascript the semantic, the syntax of the propositional calculus?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online)?

Comment: For anything non-trivial, you're probably going to want either a recursive-descent parser or a state machine (either your own, or something you can configure). Mentioning them primarily so you know what to search for. Don't get sucked into trying to find a JavaScript-based regular expression solution, it will be a massive waste of time.

Comment: I was asked to make a labeled lambda calculus parser and resolutor, but since I'm not accustomed to code like this, I thought to start from a simpler formalism, like the propositional calculus.
If you say that recursive-descent parser or a state machine are two possibile ways to implement this project, I'll check it out.
Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using [antlr v3](http://www.antlr.org/)'s javascript target.

here's a question that has the grammer you're looking for:  [ANTLR Propositional Logic Evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050433/antlr-propositional-logic-evaluator)

and another question you might find helpful:
[ANTLR JavaScript Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540429/antlr-javascript-target)